# How to create proper size drawable on android as it was designed on px image - knowing dimensions,density, etc.?

Tags: android, pixel-density

I would really know how to create proper drawables for android mobile phones.
According to lessons from udacity "[Android Design for Developers](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-design-for-developers--ud862)".

Aim: create identical size drawable on screen as it was designed on image.
What do I know:

1. screens size 1440x2560 px

[image]

2. density is 560 dpi - which is xxxhdpi
3. so, screen in dp dimensions is 411x731 dp
4. icon is 158x158 px
5. I know I should put this in xxxhdpi folder.

Should I scale down whole image to dp dimensions (411x731 px) and then design 150x150px "man" to keep the same size in android screen as it was created on image? How could I mange it? So far I use to create "lucky size of image"  to get proper size or I was defining custom size in code. But this not the clue. Help.

PS. please do not reffer to supporting screens android page because I were there.

---

> I do not know what px size should have "man" picture for xxxhdpi to
>   get the same size as is on image after taking screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See.
You image dimensions for xxxhdpi is 158x158 px.

Let's take mdpi as 1x.
then,
hdpi = 1.5x
xhdpi = 2x
xxhdpi = 3x
xxxhdpi = 4x

```
4x = 158x158 (let's add some margin and make it 160x160)
1x = 40x40
1.5x = 60x60
2x = 80x80
3x = 120x120
4x = 160x160
```

Comment: I think there is small misunderstanding. I do not know what px size should have "man" picture for xxxhdpi to get the same size as is on image after taking screenshot. Do you follow me?

Comment: if this screenshot was taken from xxxhdpi device, than you just slice out the man out of picture and save it in drawable-xxxhdpi folder.
Then on any device (regarding of exact size of density value) it should be exactly the same physical size (not px, but cm). It's a good practice to scale down the image for other density-buckets as well (so that android doesn't do it for you in runtime).